# Google Play Music media keys not working 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, music

Whenever I try pause or next/previous on Ubuntu 14.04 or Ubuntu Gnome 14.04, nothing happens. No other music apps are open, and I have it set to global in Chrome. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us any terminal output?

Comment: I don't know what to put into terminal. Sorry, I'm bad with all this stuff

Comment: run the program from the terminal. It should output any relevant errors there during runtime.

Comment: Run chrome from terminal? Because all it is is just a web app.

Comment: Oh, this is the web app? I mistakenly thought you were referring to the native application. The note about Chrome was quite confusing to me. I don't often think of web pages as capturing media key presses.

Comment: On Windows or even Elementary OS, it works fine. Just not on 14.04 for some reason :/

Comment: But yeah. it's a web app, just Google Music running on Chrome, and I use it entirely for music, so I can't use Ubuntu 14.04 because of that :/

Answer (score 14):

Try disabling the media keys and restarting Chrome:

1. navigate to Keyboard > Shortcuts > Sound and Media;
2. select the keybinding of interest and press backspace to disable it;
3. do it for all media keys;
4. restart Chrome.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks you, answer should be accepted. Of course the media keys do not seem to work for native apps now. Any idea how to get both to work?

Comment: Just to add a 2nd data point: it didn't work for me. I'll post another answer here if I figure out another way.

Comment: This worked for me although I didn't need to restart Chrome.